# how to check a mail sent by java application is read or not?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, liferay-6

Please help me on this requirement.

We are sending mails to users using java application.

Now, we want to implement the below features.

1. When the mail is open/read by the user, then we want to save the time stamp in the database.
2. How many times the person opens the mail which we sent to him/her.

Please help me how to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: we dont provide any code here . post us _What have you tried ?_ .please read [ask]

Comment: i guess second one is not possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, this is impossible to get with 100% certainty. Email is normally fire and forget. However, there are some commonly used tricks to get an idea.

You can make the email an html email with a 1 pixel image embedded. As you send out the emails, you make a new image url for each outgoing email (I'd go for one per recipient) and save that url somewhere (for example in a database). You also have to set up a very simple server that will accept requests to the image urls you're creating. That server then responds to those calls sending each of them the same simple 1pixel image and noting which url was called (this can be done with a simple Apache server, using access logs to track the urls). Every time a user opens your email, his email client would normally go and load the image. Your server then gets a request and since you made the url unique for every recipient, you know who opened the email when. Caveats: if the email is forwarded, other people can activate that same link; the user can configure the client to not open images; etc.
If you look around a bit, you might find some off the shelf solutions as well.

If you happen to also have control over the email server and/or the email clients of your users, you have a lot of other possibilities.